# Cmake in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, cmake, android-ndk

I try to make a android studio NDK  project 
It says  
 
`Gradle sync failed: Failed to find CMake.
                Install from Android Studio under File/Settings/Appearance & Behavior/System Settings/Android SDK/SDK Tools/CMake.
                Expected CMake executable at E:\android\sdkstudio\cmake\bin\cmake.exe.
                Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)`

I cant find cmake in SDK tool --- And i run it on **64bit** 
Thanks for the answers....

Comment: Could it be that the path to Android SDK you installed has spaces? If the installation is corrupt, you can easily reinstall the full SDK from Android Studio SDK manager.

Comment: Thanks for the answer....Yeah....I did that many times....I search a lot but everyone just said run on 64

Comment: You mean you can run `E:\android\sdkstudio\cmake\bin\cmake.exe` on command line, but Android Studio cannot?

Comment: No theres no cmake at all ..i open a project(c++) in android studio and then say no cmake install it from sdk tool ..but theres nothing

Comment: https://imgrpost.com/image/IR6kz

Comment: .https://imgrpost.com/image/IROmE

Comment: https://imgrpost.com/image/IR573

Comment: If I were in your situation, I'd try to download the latest Android Studio from scratch from https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/install/3.1.2.0/android-studio-ide-173.4720617-windows.exe.

Comment: I bet your Android Studio version is out of date. Update to at least 2.0 and probably 3.0 or higher as of today. Also make sure your SDK update sites include "Android Repository"